# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'TagId'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Im new to MVC and I had this problem, please help me,
when I try to upload an image to my website project ,this error come up 
"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'TagId'."
this is my view model:

```
@model ImageSharingWithAuth.Models.ImageView

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload an Image";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title </h2>

@{Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Images", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype ="multipart/form-data"});}

<fieldset>
    <legend >
        Enter Image Information
    </legend>
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <p>
        Caption: @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Caption)
                @Html.ValidationMessage("Caption")

    </p>
    <p>

       Select a tag : @Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.TagId , ViewBag.Tags as SelectList)

    </p>
    <p>
        Description :<br />
        @Html.TextAreaFor(model=> model.Description,5,40,null)
                @Html.ValidationMessage("Description")

    </p>
    <p>

        Date taken: @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.DateTaken)
                @Html.ValidationMessage("DateTaken")


    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="file" name="ImageFile" />
    </p>
    <p>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

    </p>
</fieldset>

<p>@ViewBag.Message</p>
<p> @Html.ValidationSummary() </p>
@{Html.EndForm(); }
```

this is the get and set for uploading:

```
private ImageSharingDB db = new ImageSharingDB();
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Upload()
        {

            CheckAda();

            //string userid = GetLoggedInUser();
            //if (userid == null) {
            //    return ForceLogin();
            //}
            //else

            {
                ViewBag.Message = "";
                //IEnumerable<Tag> tags = db.Tags;

               ViewBag.Tags = new SelectList(db.Tags, "Id", "Name",1);


                return View();
            }
        }
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Upload(ImageView image, HttpPostedFileBase ImageFile)
        {

            CheckAda();
            TryUpdateModel(image);


            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                String userid = GetLoggedInUser();
                //if (userid != null)
                //{
                //    return ForceLogin();
                //}
                //else 

                    User user = db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.Userid.Equals(userid));

                    if (user != null)
                    {


                        // save image info on the db


                        Image imageEntity = new Image();
                        imageEntity.Id = image.Id;
                        imageEntity.Caption = image.Caption;
                        imageEntity.Description = image.Description;
                        imageEntity.DateTaken = image.DateTaken;

                        imageEntity.Approved = false;
                        imageEntity.User = user;
                        imageEntity.TagId = image.TagId;


                        if (ImageFile != null && ImageFile.ContentLength > 0)
                        {
                            db.Images.Add(imageEntity);
                            db.SaveChanges();
                            String imgFileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/img-"+imageEntity.Id+".jpg");
                            ImageFile.SaveAs(imgFileName);

                            return View("Details", image);

                            //return RedirectToAction("Details", imageEntity.Id);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewBag.Message = "No such image file specified";
                            return View();
                        }


                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.Message = "No Scuh userid registered";
                        return View();

                    }



            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Please crrect the errorsin the form!";
                return View();
            }

        }
```

this the model for ImageView :

```
namespace ImageSharingWithAuth.Models
{
    public class ImageView
    {

        [Required]
        [StringLength(40)]
        public String Caption { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int TagId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public String Description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
         [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}",ApplyFormatInEditMode=true)]
        public DateTime DateTaken { get; set; }

        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id;
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public String Userid { get; set; }
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public String TagName { get; set; }





    }
}
```

and the model for Image:

```
namespace ImageSharingWithAuth.Models
{
    public class Image
    {

        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public virtual int Id {get;set;}
        [MaxLength(40)]
        public virtual string Caption { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public virtual string Description { get; set; }
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:d}")]
        public virtual DateTime DateTaken { get; set; }

        public virtual bool Approved { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("User")]

        public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Tag")]
        public virtual int TagId { get; set; }
        public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }

        public Image() {
            Approved = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You need to put values into `ViewBag.Tags` in your `[httppost]` also.

Answer (score 1):

try this in else block in httpPost method of controller

```
 else
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "Please crrect the errorsin the form!";
                 ViewBag.Tags = new SelectList(db.Tags, "Id", "Name",1);
                return View();
            }
```